# Input fields of jquery dialog box freezes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog box with a button and checkbox on it. On open function of dialog box i have following code:

```
$('#dialog1').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('#dialog1').parent('.ui-dialog').css('zIndex', 26)
            .nextAll('.ui-widget-overlay').css('zIndex', 25);
    }
});
```

Now after I click a button in the dialog, a new dialog opens:

```
$('#dialog2').dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('#dialog2').parent('.ui-dialog').css('zIndex', 27)
            .nextAll('.ui-widget-overlay').css('zIndex', 25);
    }
});
```

And after the click on "close" icon of dialog2 following event is triggered:

```
   $('dialog2').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
              $('#dialog1').close();
              $('div').remove('#dialog2');
         });
```

The problem is after the above event, the input fields of dialog1 freezes and is not clickable. I checked the z-index but found it right. Can somebody help why the input fields are not clikable.

Comment: Please add your HTML of your dialogs

Comment: In your close event, you close both dialogs. So the input of dialog1 would no longer be visible. The issue is not clear. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example